# Why does my code stop after processing one html?

Tags: python, html

I have created a code, but it stops after one html is processed. Am I overlooking something?
I would appreciate the help!

```
import textwrap
import os
import pandas as pd
import textwrap
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

directory ='C:/Research syntheses - Meta analysis/SeekingAlpha/Tests'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith('.html'):
        fname = os.path.join(directory,filename)
        with open(fname,errors='ignore') as f:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(),'html.parser')

print('{:<30} {:<70}'.format('Name', 'Answer'))
print('-' * 101)
for answer in soup.find('div',class_='content_part hid', id='article_qanda').find_all('strong'):
    txt = answer.get_text(strip=True)

    s = answer.find_next_sibling()
    while s:
        if s.name == 'strong' or s.find_all('strong'):
            break
        if s.name == 'p':
            txt += ' ' + s.get_text(strip=True)
        s = s.find_next_sibling()

    txt = ('\n' + ' '*31).join(textwrap.wrap(txt))
    print('{:<30} {:<70}'.format('exec', txt))
```

Comment: In for loop you open `.htm` file every time in `soup` variable, it means that at the end you only have the last `.html` file.

Comment: @CC7052 and how should i change this to open all htmls in my directory?

Comment: Does your code need edit? second `for` loop start wihout `indent`??

Comment: @Jose What exactly do you mean by "stops processing"? Does the script freeze? Have you tried adding some debugging print statements to see what the code is actually doing?

Comment: @ekhumoro no the output is only from one html, while i would have expected (since all elements are also there in the other htmls) to have also output from the other htmls.

Comment: @Jose Well, it looks like your expectations are wrong. Put in some debugging print statements to see what the code is actually doing: e.g. `print('file:', fname)`, `print('text:' len(txt))`, etc.

Comment: @Jose PS: and please fix the indentation in your code example.

Comment: @ekhumoro i fixed the indent, but it still only prints (indeed the last) html. But i don't understand how to fix it in my code, could someone help?

Comment: @Jose Move everything inside the with-block.

Comment: @ekhumoro YES, so simple, many thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to ekhumoro, the answer is:

```
import textwrap
import os
import pandas as pd
import textwrap
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

directory ='C:/Research syntheses - Meta analysis/SeekingAlpha/Tests'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith('.html'):
        fname = os.path.join(directory,filename)
        with open(fname,errors='ignore') as f:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(),'html.parser')

        print('{:<30} {:<70}'.format('Name', 'Answer'))
        print('-' * 101)
        for answer in soup.find('div',class_='content_part hid', id='article_qanda').find_all('strong'):
            txt = answer.get_text(strip=True)

            s = answer.find_next_sibling()
            while s:
                if s.name == 'strong' or s.find_all('strong'):
                    break
                if s.name == 'p':
                    txt += ' ' + s.get_text(strip=True)
                s = s.find_next_sibling()

            txt = ('\n' + ' '*31).join(textwrap.wrap(txt))
            print('{:<30} {:<70}'.format('exec', txt))
```